# Scan 10 integer from user

Tags: java, arrays

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter 1 Integer number " +i);
            value[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
```

How can I increase the number **1** inside the output string to be increased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you mean ? You want the number inside your output string to be increased?
Since you're inside the for it will always be increased.
If you want to print from 1-10 instead of 0-9 just do (i+1)

Like this.

```
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
      System.out.println("Enter " + (i+1) +" Integer number ");
      value[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
```